# Grid view display images at the end of the screen

Tags: android

However displaying images doesn't perform on item click listener. When i click on space of screen before the images displaying start, the required image set as wallpaper. But i want to know why these images are displaying after so much space

Comment: Please help me.i am in trouble & not able to solve it..

Comment: I am trying it from last 5 hours but didn't get any solution from anywhere. plz help me

Comment: Sorry, the question seems to be of development related in nature. It is a out of topic. You'd get better chance by asking it in [so] .

Comment: how can i asked it in stack overflow..every time it gives me error